# Randomly select 1 value from rows with multiple values; create a new column with cleaned data

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Seems like a simple function but cannot seem to find a good way to do it on R. I have a column, P, that has many rows with multiple inputs:

P:

[340000, 410000]
[450000, 450000]
530000
110000
[330000, 440000]
510000
440000
620000
320000

Desired P1 (the * values should be randomly selected): (apologies for the spacing, the spacing is just so each value is a different line)

340000*

450000*

530000
110000
440000*

510000
440000
620000
320000

I want to build a new column that randomly selects 1 value from every row vector starting with "[" in column P  and then spits out a new column, P1, with the corrected values+the other independent row values. This is part of a larger effort to clean the column so it is usable for regression.

Right now, I've come up with this tidyverse code as the best option for mutating :

```
foo <- data.frame(P=="[")
foo %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(P1 = sample(P, 1))
```

But this isn't returning the output I need. Asside from sample(), I'm not sure what else can be used for random selection from a [] vector. I'm wondering what the best way to go about this would be?? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Could you provide few rows of your data that we can copy/paste and use to test the solutions? You can use `dput(head(df))` to share first 6 rows. Also show expected output for the data shared.

Comment: @RonakShah yes, i'll edit it into the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove `[]` from the column values, split data on comma and get each value in different row. For each row you can then select 1 random value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(P1 = gsub('\\[|\\]', '', P), 
         row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(P1, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  slice_sample(n = 1) %>%
  #In older version of dplyr use sample_n
  #sample_n(1)
  ungroup %>%
  select(-row)

#    P                P1    
#  <chr>            <chr> 
#1 [340000, 410000] 340000
#2 [450000, 450000] 450000
#3 530000           530000
#4 110000           110000
#5 [330000, 440000] 440000
#6 510000           510000
#7 440000           440000
#8 620000           620000
#9 320000           320000
```

---

In base R you can implement the same logic with

```
df$P1 <- sapply(strsplit(gsub('\\[|\\]', '', df$P), ',\\s*'), sample, 1)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(P = c("[340000, 410000]", "[450000, 450000]", 
"530000", "110000", "[330000, 440000]", "510000", "440000", "620000", 
"320000")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: Wow thanks!! It worked out. However, there is one thing: in the posts there are some values with u'140000' (a number XXXXXX) post and I'm not sure how I should change it to 140000 alone. I tried replace() function but it turned the data into a list. What would you suggest?

Comment: Do you have string with `"u'140000'"` ? After `separate_rows` try with `mutate(P1 = replace(P1, P1 == "u'140000'", 140000))`